# Pointers changing value of variables

Tags: c, pointers

I am passing three numbers into my program , lets say `6 2 8` i have function , which generates random number in intervals of those numbers e.g

```
1 number = 0<= number <=6
2 number = 0<= number <=2
3 number = 0<= number <=8
```

i have declared function for it which works fine

```
double random(int a)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    double rnd = (((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)) * a);
    return rnd;
}
```

then i have final number lets say `10`
what i am trying to do , is random generate number from interval of first two numbers = from

```
1 number = 0<= number <=6
2 number = 0<= number <=2
```

im doing it like this

```
 podiel_one=random(m_one);
 podiel_two=random(m_two);
podiel_three= getlast(m_three,podiel_one,podiel_two,m_final,m_one,m_two);
```

(i scan said numbers into variables so m_one = 6 , m_two =2 , m_three=8, m_final=10)
and then i find the final number with simple math

```
podiel_three = m_final-(podiel_one + podiel_two )
```

this works fine , but i want to fix the case , when final number wont be from its interval ( 0 <= number <=8 )
i have made function for it

```
double getlast(double m_three,double* podiel_one,double* podiel_two,double m_final,double m_one,double m_two){

double testt=(podiel_one+podiel_two);
double tmp_three=m_final-testt;

if(tmp_three>=0 && tmp_three <= m_three){
    return tmp_three;
}
else{
    *podiel_one=random(m_one);
    *podiel_two=random(m_two);
    getlast(m_three,podiel_one, podiel_two,m_final,m_one,m_two);
}
return 1;
}
```

this function does following = if the final number isnt from its interval , it assign new random value into variables and do the math again and again until said number is from interval. The problem is that when i try to compile it throws error and warnings /errors

```
 invalid operands to binary + (have 'double *' and 'double *')
 |error: incompatible type for argument 3 of 'getlast'
 error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'getlast
 note: expected 'double *' but argument is of type 'double'|
```

Being pretty new in C language im lost right now , how can i fix it and make my program work?

Comment: Try `*podiel_one + *podiel_two`

Comment: `testt` is going to be the result of adding two pointers. adding together the numbers that represent arbitrary memory addresses is basically useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused between operations performed on the pointer and operations performed on the values being pointed to.  A pointer represents and address in memory.  Adding to a pointer calculates the address an offset from the address that the pointer points to. That is only useful when the pointer represents a position in an array.  In your situation, you want to perform those operations on the value being pointed to.  That is, instead of

```
double testt=(podiel_one+podiel_two);
```

You want

```
double testt=(*podiel_one+*podiel_two);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `podiel_one` and `podiel_two` are declared as `double`:

```
double podiel_one, podiel_two;
```

So when you call `getlast` you need to pass the address of those:

```
podiel_three= getlast(m_three, &podiel_one, &podiel_two, m_final, m_one, m_two);
```

Then in `getlast` you try to add 2 pointers together, which is not what you want. You need to deference the pointers to get the values they are pointing to:

```
double testt = *podiel_one + *podiel_two;
```